International to domestic connection at LAX
International flight landing at LAX at 12:50 and departing on a separate domestic ticket at 16:30. Is that enough time to go through immigration, security, luggage, etc?
Arrival via Singapore and departing via United. I am unsure of the terminals. Late September.

It always depends on the risk you will take. There is never a guarantee. I would check online the delay of your first flight for some days, to have an idea: some flights have much more delay (length, frequency) then others. If you arrive at 12:50 you have enough time, but if...

What are the incoming and departing airlines and terminals (or ideally, the flight numbers)? On what date?

You should edit the question, to add information. In any case, the flight seems to arrive on time or earlier. 21 may it arrived 14:00, 20 April: 14:20, 12 April: 14:23. If no typhoons, I would bet on the connection.

Just to clarify: I listed the 3 exceptions, else it was on time

@GiacomoCatenazzi if it arrives at 14:20, would I still have enough time?

Such page may help: https://awt.cbp.gov/  You may see: 17 min average to 77 max (in case of delays), If you want to be sure (at extra price) buy a single ticket. Else: if you are not flying to "nowhere" probably there are later flights and maybe other airlines, so you may get last-minute extra flight for cheap, in case of needs

I already bought the tickets. United changed the itinerary so they offered a free change. There are later flights if I miss the connection.

In your case, you'll be arriving at TBIT and have to check-in for your next flight at Terminal 7.
The check-in deadline for United domestic flights at LAX seems to be at 45 minutes before scheduled departure, so 15:45.
This means you have 2h55 to:

Deplane
Get to passport control
Queue and get through
Wait for your bags
Go through customs
Exit TBIT and either walk to Terminal 7 (a bit over half a mile) or take a shuttle to get there.
At some point you will have to get from the arrivals to the departures floor
Find your check-in counter and check-in/drop your bags

After that you will still have to go through security and to your gate before it closes.
If all goes well, this is most definitely doable (should probably take about 1h-1h30, though it depends a lot on where you are seated on the incoming flight, whether you can use the APC kiosks, whether you have status and can skip queues...). However, if there are any issues, remember that if you miss any of the deadlines for the second flight, you will be considered a no-show, and your ticket is likely to be cancelled (along with further segments on the same ticket, like a return flight). In that case, you have to book and pay for a new flight at your own expense, at last minute prices.
United does not have an official "flat tire policy". They say that they will "generally" rebook people who arrive within 30 minutes on to the next flight, but you can't count on it.
Depending on your final destination, the 16:30 may also be the last flight of the day. In that case you may need to rebook on a different airline, or pay for a hotel, as well as transfers to/from there, meals, etc.
Here you have probably about 1h30 of buffer. We can't decide for you whether you think that's enough.

Thanks for the great detail. I think the biggest key is to arrive on time and not get held up at immigration and security. I have never been to LAX but I can walk half mile in 7 minutes.
